# Historical URL resolving to new ActionResult instead of 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-status-code-301

I have a controller that has a parent and a child actionresult.

```
[Route("parent/", Name = "parent")]
public ActionResult parent()

[Route("parent/{child}/", Name = "child")]
public ActionResult child(string myparam)
```

If I put in the URL www.mysite.com/parent all is good.

If I address the child with a parameter @Url.RouteUrl("child", new { param = myparam }), all good www.mysite.com/parent/child

However I do have a historical page that I need to 301 www.mysite.com/parent/child.htm.

When I put in the above url it triggers my parent actionresult. www.mysite.com/parent when I need it to 301 to www.mysite.com/parent/child

Comment: How are you adding the 301? Through URL rewrite module, through .NET routing, or some other means?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Seems it was a VS glitch. Closed then opened VS and the problem resolved itself.